# Python Pandas: groupby date and count new records for each period

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I'm trying to use Python Pandas to count daily returning visitors to my website over a time period.

Example data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,2,3,1,3], 'date':['2012-09-29','2012-09-30','2012-09-30','2012-10-01','2012-10-01']})

print df1
         date  user_id
0  2012-09-29        1
1  2012-09-30        2
2  2012-09-30        3
3  2012-10-01        1
4  2012-10-01        3
```

What I'd like to have as final result:

```
df1_result = pd.DataFrame({'count_new':[1,2,0], 'date':['2012-09-29','2012-09-30','2012-10-01']})

print df1_result
   count_new        date
0          1  2012-09-29
1          2  2012-09-30
2          0  2012-10-01
```

In the first day there is 1 new user because user 1 appears for the first time.

In the second day there are 2 new users: user 2 and user 3 both appear for the first time.

Finally in the third day there are 0 new users: user 1 and user 3 have both already appeared in previous periods.

So far I have been looking into merging two copies of same dataframe and shifting one by a date, but without success:

```
pd.merge(df1, df1.user_id.shift(-date), on = 'date').groupby('date')['user_id_y'].nunique()
```

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> (df1
     .groupby(['user_id'], as_index=False)['date']  # Group by `user_id` and get first date.
     .first()
     .groupby(['date'])  # Group result on `date` and take counts.
     .count()
     .reindex(df1['date'].unique())  # Reindex on original dates.
     .fillna(0))  # Fill null values with zero.
            user_id
date               
2012-09-29        1
2012-09-30        2
2012-10-01        0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to add a new column `Isreturning` (in case you need to analysis on Returning customer in the future)

```
df['Isreturning']=df.groupby('user_id').cumcount()
```

---

Only show new customer

```
df.loc[df.Isreturning==0,:].groupby('date')['user_id'].count()
Out[840]: 
date
2012-09-29    1
2012-09-30    2
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
```

Or you can :

```
df.groupby('date')['Isreturning'].apply(lambda x : len(x[x==0]))
Out[843]: 
date
2012-09-29    1
2012-09-30    2
2012-10-01    0
Name: Isreturning, dtype: int64
```